# Web application deployment on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Which is the best strategy to deploy .net Web application on AWS?
1. On EC2 instance where on single instance deploy both application and MS sql database.
2. On elastic beanstalk where the application is deployed on EC2 instance and database in RDS.

OR any other strategy.
What do you think?

Comment: Depends on many things. For example, option 1 is cheaper then 2. But then 2 can be more reliable and easier to manage than 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on your use case and budget. Running on the single instance is affordable but will be a single point of failure, and in case your instance goes down, your entire web app is gone. On top of that, any updates can be a nightmare. This is only ideal for development environments.

If you deploy via Beanstalk with external database, it will be expensive but it will be exponentially more fault tolerant. If your EC2 instance goes down, it will get replaced automatically (though you can achieve this even when using single instance. For prod, you must decouple your database instance from your environment, so you can run a database instance in Amazon RDS and configure your application to connect to it on launch. This enables you to connect multiple environments to a database, terminate an environment without affecting the database, and perform seamless updates with blue-green deployments.

Also, the 2nd option will be pretty convenient. All you have to do it give EB your application source bundle and it will do all the legwork. You can [read more about EB and RDS setup here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.RDS.html).

Comment: Btw you can have both your app and db on one instance in Elastic Beanstalk also which is slightly better than running it on ec2 but it still comes with most caveats of a single point of failure.